# How do I write php code on a created PHP file

Tags: php

For part of my website I need to be able to write php code to a file with php. For example:

```
$myfile = fopen("event.php", "w");
$txt = "
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "events";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(isset($_POST['create_event'])){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO event (event_name, date_created) 
            VALUES (
            '".$_POST['event_name']."',
            '".date('Y-m-d')."'
            )";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 

} ?> ";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

How can I insert a php file inside the file I created. But, instead of creating the file, it throws an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'localhost' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\reap2017\event\create.php on line 8
```

Comment: You forgot to add your error

Comment: sorry I already add now sir.

Comment: I think you need to escape your " signs. Example you can use \"

Or else it will try to find the variable localhost.

Answer (score 0):

A string is indicated by two quotes. As soon as there is a second quote the compiler is going to think your string ends there. However, you want to have a string within a string for your server variables.

There are two ways to do this:
1. Using single `'` and double `"` quotes
2. Escaping the quote character with a backslash `\"`

Furthermore you'll need to wrap any variable names in your string in curly braces `{ }` to prevent PHP from interpolating your variables. Basically PHP even recognises variables in strings, and the braces tell it to use the literal text instead of the variable value.

Comment: the \" works fine but I am now getting an error...the file already creates but Notice: Undefined variable: servername.. on the created file it looks like this <?php  = "localhost"; ?>

Comment: @JanKlenschAsentista why not define contents of $txt with single quotes and escapes single quotes inside $txt with \\' ? think it s easier and less work that way: you dont need to escape $ signs inside single quotes

Comment: I am having a hard time here... how can I do this the same on the created file?  `$sql = "INSERT INTO event (event_name, date_created) 
            VALUES (
            '".$_POST['event_name']."',
            '".date('Y-m-d')."'
            )";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);`

Comment: What exactly do you mean? (Additional note: There is a MySQL function called `NOW()`, just so you know)